# Java double with no decimal place doesn't multiply correctly?

Tags: java, math

I'm really sorry to ask this but I'm completely losing my mind over Java math at this point and its multitude of quirks. I have a function that converts from geographic longitude/latitude into a relative X/Y graph. (not important) But during testing I ran into a problem where a double multiplication, which should result in a double with no decimal place (e.g. 100.0), is returning an incorrect value.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
double DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR = 111329;
double E6 = Double.valueOf(1E6);

double lng1 = 44.34648;
double lat1 = -76.888694;
double lng2 = 44.346356;
double lat2 = -76.888215;

xyFromLongLat(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2);


public static Pair<Double, Double> xyFromLongLat(double long0, double lat0, double long1, double lat1) {
    double x = Math.round(((long1 - long0) * longitudeDistanceAtLatitude(lat0)) * E6);
    double y = Math.round(((lat1 - lat0) * DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR) * E6);
    return new Pair<Double, Double>(x, y);
}
```

Double y results in 5.3326591E7? e.g. (-76.888694 - -76.888215) = -0.000479 * 111329.0 = -53.326591 * 1000000.0 SHOULD EQUAL -53326591.

Instead it equals: 5.332659099984012E7

```
(lat1 - lat0) * DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR
(-76.888694 - -76.888215) * 111329.0 = -53.326591 <- This is correct

((lat1 - lat0) * DEGREE_DISTANCE_AT_EQUATOR) * E6
((-76.888694 - -76.888215) * 111329.0) * 1000000.0 = 5.332659099984012E7 <- What is this?!
```

I have no clue why this is an issue. At some point there's probably some automatic conversion to a long or float possibly because the result has no decimal places yet is supposed to be a double?

I'm really sorry if this is an obvious problem. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated as are any edits that clarify any terminology I've misused. Thanks!

*Note that I realize Math.round returns a long. This was the latest attempt, without the rounding Y produces the same incorrect value.*

Comment: see related [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Your `lat1 - lat0` computation is -76.888215 - -76.888694, not the other way round. It doesn't help that your variables go from being 1-based to being 1-based, but that's basically why you're getting a sign different to what you expect.

Comment: Is your problem the .000001% error?

Comment: @donfuxx: I knew someone would post about precision. I get it. Now where in Goldberg's paper does it explain how to multiply -53.326591 * 1E6 in Java and get the correct value? I don't want to be rude but these type of "fundamentals" answers do not educate unless it helps with the problem. I'm not only looking for why this is a problem, but how to solve it. Seriously, sorry if I appear unappreciative.

Comment: @donfuxx: Arg, it is simply a precision problem. I apologize. You're all right.

Answer (score 1):

It's a scientific notation and means 5.3326 multiplied by 10<sup>7</sup>.

So E here stands for 10, followed by the exponent of 10.